# Выровнять по высоте текст с разным кол-вом символов

Tags: html, css

У меня есть 4 блока, не могу найти и понять как можно выровнять разное кол-во символов.
Сверху на скрине как задумано
Снизу как у меня(Там же и стили которых еще нет)...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: из описания не понятно, что конкретно Вы хотите выровнять?

Comment: Скорее всего вам поможет flex. https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&q=flexbox+выравнивание+по+вертикали

Comment: В данном конкретном случае нужно лишь зафиксировать ширину, выбрать правильный шрифт и его размер и убедиться, что текст занимает ровно пять строк. Если же ширина нужна резиновая или текст может быть разный, нужно уточнение, что именно ожидается, когда число строк изменится

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое эт flex-box - https://jsfiddle.net/9kpyhoyn/

```
.row{
  display: flex;
}

.item{
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: и где тут выравнивание по высоте?

Comment: если у родителя задать display: flex, то дети автоматом по высоте выровняется

Comment: но не выровнялись, или кто-то из нас не так понял вопрос